# no entiendo el segundo y tercer principio de solid

Tags: java, arquitectura

Single Responsibility: cada objeto debe tener una única responsabilidad
Open/Close: abierto para la extensión, clausurado ante cambios

Liskov Substitution: las clases hijas deben poder ser tratadas como las clases padre

Interface Segregation: es preferible muchas interfaces con pocos métodos a pocas interfaces con muchos métodos

Dependency Inversion: los componentes deben depender de abstracciones, no de implementaciones concretas

alguien que sepa me puede explicar ?

Comment: Si te lees [SOLID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) en la wikipedia a mi me parece que se entiende. Si tienes un problema para entender algo ya haces una pregunta exacta. Fijate que conforme la tienes hecha ahora hay confusión porque en la respuesta que te han dado hablan de la **S** y la **I**. Para mi la 2ª y 3ª son la **O** y la **L**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open/Close: Significa que tienes que hacer un diseño para que, al agregar nueva funcionalidad no tengas que tocar el código ya existente.

Imaginemos que tienes una aplicación de facturación y varios tipos de clientes, definidos en un enum, y para facturar haces algo como:

```
switch (cliente.getTipoCliente) {
case TipoClienteA:
   facturarClienteA(cliente);
   break;
case TipoClienteB:
   facturarClienteB(cliente);
   break;
```

Si añades un tipo de cliente, tienes que ir a todos los switches e ifs de tipoCliente y añadir la lógica, modificando código que ya funciona.

Como alternativa, imagina que defines una interface `Facturador`, y que en el enum de TipoCliente tienes un método que, para cada instancia, te proporciona una implementación de `Facturador` adecuada al tipo de cliente. Entonces el código de arriba te queda como:

```
Facturador facturador = cliente.getTipoCliente.getFacturador();
facturador.facturarCliente(cliente);
```

Si añades un nuevo cliente, sólo necesitas implementar el facturador y añadir el elemento al enum.

Otras opciones son sistemas de plugin y demás.

Dicho lo dicho, siempre he encontrado que es el criterio más complicado de implementar, y lo aplico sólo para bloques bien definidos (recuerda que SOLID son recomendaciones, no reglas absolutas).

---

El principio de substitución es que una instancia de una subclase siempre debe funcionar de forma coherente a como lo haría una instancia de la superclase. Por ejemplo, imagina

```
 public class A {

   public int valorAbsoluto(int val) {
     return val < 0 ? -val : val;
   }
 }

 public class B extends A {
   @Override
   public int valorAbsoluto(int val) {
     return 0;
   }
 }
```

No tiene mucho sentido, ¿no? Si pasas una instancia de `B` a un método x que acepte un `A`, puedes acabar tener un `DivideByCeroError` a pesar de que x haya hecho las comprobaciones correctas.

El problema es que la instancia de `B` no actúa como una instancia de `A`, a pesar de que también es instancia de `A` (por ser instancia de una subclase de `A`).

El principio de Liskov añade que, además, se tiene que tener en cuenta la historia. Imagina que cada método de `B` cumple la implementación de `A`, con la excepción de que después de llamar a cada método de B debes llamar a un método `reset()`, o que los métodos de `B` se deben de llamar en determinado orden. Un código que espere usar instancias de A no tendrá en cuenta esas restricciones, lo que volverá a dar en resultados inesperados/erróneos.

Answer (score 3):

Single Responsibility: cada objeto debe tener una única responsabilidad Open/Close: abierto para la extensión, clausurado ante cambios

Mas o menos quiere decir que cuando vallas a crear una clase esta solo tiene que tener los metodos que que sera utilizados en x funcionalidad. y no declarar todos los metodos que se van a utilizar en el sistema.

Este principio trata de destinar cada clase a una finalidad sencilla y concreta.

Interface Segregation: Este quiere decir que si un usuario no necesita una interfaz, no lo obliges a utilizarla.

Aca te dejo un link que explica muy bien los principios de solid

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp

Answer (score 3):

Single Responsability o SRP Cada objeto debe de tener una unica responsabilidad, esto puede ser traducido o aplicado como: Cada objeto debe de tener una unica razón para cambiar, para poder explicar esto mejor, veamos el siguiente ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos la siguiente clase Cliente que se encarga de almacenar a un cliente en la base de datos:

```
public class ServicioCliente
{
    private ClienteDb _clienteAccesoADatos = new ClienteDb();

    public void GuardarCliente(Cliente entidad)
    {
         if(!ValidarCliente(entidad))
              throw new InvalidOperationException("El cliente no es válido");

         _clienteAccesoADatos.Guardar(entidad)
    }

    public bool ValidarCliente(Cliente entidad)
    {
        bool resultado = true;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entidad.Nombre))
           result &= false;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entidad.Apellidos))
           result &= false;

        return resultado;
   }
}
```

En este caso nuestra clase hace 2 cosas:

1. Verifica que el cliente es válido.
2. Almacena el cliente en la base de datos.

Lo cual significa que si deseamos cambiar algo tenemos 2 razones para cambiar la clase por lo que estamos violando el principio de Responsabilidad Única (de ahora en mas SRP) En este caso lo que podemos hacer es dividir nuestra clase en dos clases. De esta forma:

```
public class ServicioCliente
{
    private ClienteDb _clienteAccesoADatos = new ClienteDb();
    private ValidadorCliente _validador = new ValidadorCliente();

    public void GuardarCliente(Cliente entidad)
    {
         if(!_validador.ValidarCliente(entidad))
              throw new InvalidOperationException("El cliente no es válido");

         _clienteAccesoADatos.Guardar(entidad)
    }        
}

Internal class ValidadorCliente
{
    public bool ValidarCliente(Cliente entidad)
    {
        bool resultado = true;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entidad.Nombre))
           result &= false;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entidad.Apellidos))
           result &= false;

        return resultado;
   }
}
```

De esta forma ahora tenemos dos clases que tienen una sola razón para ser cambiadas.

1. Cambiar el método de almacenamiento para el caso de Servicio cliente
2. Cambiar el la forma de validación para el caso de ValidadorCliente

Si bien este principio normalmente se aplica a clases también puede ser aplicado a los métodos en una clase. Una buena forma de detectar si se está cumpliendo con el principio SRP es agregando comentarios de lo que hace un método/clase, veamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
 public void GuardarCliente(Cliente entidad)
    {
         bool esValido = true;
         // Verifica si el cliente es válido
         if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entidad.Nombre)
              esValido = false;
         if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entidad.Apellidos)
             esValido = false;
         if(entidad.edad < 18)
             esValido = false;

         // Busca en la base de datos si el cliente existe
         Cliente cliente = __clienteAccesoADatos.ObtenerPrimero(entidad.Id);
         if(cliente != null) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("El cliente ya existe");

         if(!esValido)
               throw new InvalidOperationException("El cliente es inválido");
         // guarda el cliente             
         _clienteAccesoADatos.Guardar(entidad)
    }
```

Como podemos observar en los comentarios esté metodo actualmente tiene 3 responsabilidades:

1. Verificar que el cliente es válido
2. Verificar si el cliente se encuentra en la base de datos
3. Guardar al cliente en la base de datos

Por lo que también viola el SRP, en este caso como el anterior deberemos separar el método en métodos mas pequeños que tengan una sola responsabilidad y luego hacer lo propio con la clase.

Espero con esto se clarifique el principio de responsabilidad única. Respecto a los demás principios no tengo nada que agregar.

Saludos.

Comment: La mejor forma de explicar el Principio de Responsabilidad Unica es, tal y como has escrito, a través de la afirmación “los componentes deben tener una sóla razón para ser modificados”. He escrito componentes porque debemos aplicar el Principio en todos los niveles: métodos, clases y paquetes.